# Shift Switcher versus Kile shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, kile

When I use the Shift Switcher generates conflict with shortcut keys Kile. I can not access the menu by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>. How do I use the Shift Switcher no conflict with Kile?

Answer (score 1):

You can change this by using `ccsm`

Firstly, Install It by

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then, launch it using the command `ccsm`

Select Shift Switcher

[image]

Click on the Shortcut to initiate

[image]

A new dialog will appear, Click on grab key combination

[image]

Another dialog box will appear, perform the required key combination

[image]